# Fetching data from multiple tables using transaction

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables:

- candidate: uniqid, age, gender etc.
- job: candidate_uniqid, application_date, contacted_by etc.

I want to build a profile for each candidate displaying the information from ***both*** candidate and job tables. Each candidate can have multiple job entries.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['uniqid'])) {
        $uniqid = $_GET['uniqid'];
    }
        $queryCandidate = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE uniqid = '{$uniqid}'";
        $queryJob = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE candidate_uniqid = '{$uniqid}'";

        mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
        $resultCandidate = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCandidate);
        $resultJob = mysqli_query($conn, $queryJob);
        mysqli_commit($conn);

        $rowCandidate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCandidate);

        while($rowJob = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultJob)){
            // echo $rowJob['some_value'] . '<br>';
            // display data from job table until there is nothing left to fetch
        }

        // display data from candidate table
        //echo $rowCandidate['candidate_name'] . '<br>';
        //echo $rowCandidate['phone'] . '<br>';    
?>
```

My questions are:

1. Did I use the MySQL transaction properly?
2. I am fetching data based on a variable I get from `$_GET['uniqid']`. What security measures should I keep in mind when doing so?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with SQL **[INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)**:

```
SELECT c.* , j.* FROM candidate AS c
INNER JOIN job AS j ON c.uniqid = j.candidate_uniqid
WHERE uniqid = @u
```

INNER JOIN is a keyword that concats 2 tables based on one(or more) columns that have the same value in each table, displaying all of the possible combinatons.

Here is a possible result using the INNER JOIN:

[image: example of an table got with the inner join]

As you've probably noticed, i've also added the `@u` instead of `$uniqid`. This the sort of protection i'm using,it is like a variable in SQL, which has to be set in one of the queries before the main query. The full code looks like:

```
if (isset($_GET['uniqid'])) {

    //if the uniqid is a number, use these two lines
    $uniqid = intval($_GET['uniqid']);
    mysqli_query($conn,"set @u = $uniqid"); 

    //else, if the uniqid is a string, use these two lines
    $uniqid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['uniqid']);
    mysqli_query($conn,"set @u = '$uniqid'"); 

    $query = "SELECT c.* , j.* FROM candidate AS c
        INNER JOIN job AS j ON c.uniqid = j.candidate_uniqid
        WHERE uniqid = @u";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


    }

}
```

If you (or anyone else) will need further explanations, just ask!

Comment: Clear, concise and exemplified. Thanks a lot! I'm going to rewrite all my similar queries following your approach.

Comment: I'd just like you to know, it's not 100% proof, and I'm sure it can be done a better way. But, there is not a way imune to all attacks, and this way is certainly enough if it is not a very very wide known and used site (like FB, google, YT etc. )

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. There is still one issue I can't figure out. I need to output the data from `candidate` only once, and the data from `job` multiple times (e.g. for candidates that have two or three job applications). Since `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is inside a while loop this will also display the candidate information multiple times, basically repeating itself.

Comment: Solved it using `mysqli_data_seek()`. Thanks again.